# Identifying lines with consecutive upper case letters

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for logic that searches a capital word in a line in python, like I have a *.txt:

```
aaa
adadad     
DDD_AAA    
Dasdf Daa
```

I would like to search only for the lines which have 2 or more capital words after each other (in the above case `DDD_AAA`).

Comment: What's your definition of a word?

Comment: its a huge file . I am parsing line by line .

Comment: he means is it letters only? letters and numbers? starts with underscore? etc

Comment: also DDD_AAA is one word... so how does it match 2 or more capital words?

Comment: I think perhaps "2 or more capital words" should be "...letters" ?

Comment: yes sorry for my english.. I meant letter

Answer (score 0):

```
print re.findall("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]",search_text)
```

should work to match 2 words that both start with a capital letter

for your specific example

```
lines = []
for line in file:
   if re.findall("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]",line): lines.append(line)

print lines
```

basically look into regexes!

Comment: OP seems to look for all CAPS, not starting with caps.

Comment: meh ... I was trying to demonstrate some regex stuff ... he can make a regex to match his specific definition of "Capital word"

Answer (score 0):

Regex are the way to go:

```
import re
pattern = "([A-Z]+_[A-Z]+)" # matches CAPITALS_CAPITALS only
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match: print match.group(0)
```

You have to figure out what exactly you are looking for though.

Comment: thanks jochem, but the capital letters are not known . i need to if any conscutice capital letter exits

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your definition of a "capital word" is a string of two or more uppercase alphabet (non-numeric) characters, *i.e.* `[A-Z]`, and assuming that what separates one "capital word" from another is not quite the complementary set (`[^A-Z]`) but rather the complementary set to the alphanumeric characters, *i.e.* `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, you're looking for a regex *like*

```
\b[A-Z]{2,}\b.*\b[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

I say *like* because the above is not exactly correct: `\b` counts the underscore `_` as a word character. Replace the `\b`s with `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`s wrapped in lookaround assertions (to make them zero-width, like `\b`), and you have the correct regex:

```
(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|^)[A-Z]{2,}(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])[A-Z]{2,}(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)
```

[Here's a Rubular demo.](http://rubular.com/r/BXws7Zff2X)

Finally, if you consider a one-character word, a "word", then simply do away with the `{2,}` quantifiers:

```
(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|^)[A-Z]+(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])[A-Z]+(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import re

lines = open("r1.txt").readlines()

for line in lines:
    if re.match(r'[^\w]*[A-Z]+[ _][A-Z]+[^\w]*', line) is not None:
        print line.strip("\n")
```

Output:

```
DDD_AAA
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution consider `DDDaAAA` a match?